# Initiate file download from byte stream in Flex

Tags: file, apache-flex, download

I have a situation in a Flex web app where we use a PHP webservice to lookup, read the contents and then send the Base64 encoded data back to the Flex app as part of an XML document.The Flex app must then extract, Base64 decode the byte stream and then send it DIRECTLY to the browser user (for download) without writing the file to disk.

This all must occur on the click of a "DOWNLOAD NOW" button for example.

I have been searching but all I have been finding are examples of either downloading from a URL or actually writing the byte stream to disk, which i don't want.

I need to get the stream pushed directly to the browser.  This way i can keep the files on the server protected by being outside the webspace as opposed to publicly accessible.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm not understanding your question or problem.  Isn't the act of loading a URL "sending a stream of bytes directly to the browser"?  To send a "non-web accessible file" to a browser, you'll have to write some server side code--that is web accessible--to load the file and stream the bytes back.  Depending on the file type there is no guarantee that the file will display in the browser.  It depends on the file type, and browser settings.  For example, if my browser loads a PDF I get an option to "open" or "save" because that is how my browser is set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pop a ByteArray into a Loader then use FileReference to initiate the download dialog.

```
var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
//put loader in binary mode
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_completeHandler);

//I will assume you are getting an appropriate ByteArray from your stream
var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
loader.loadBytes(data);

private function loader_completeHandler(evt:Event):void {
    //now pop a save window
    file.save(loader.data,"default_file_name.png")
}
```

*edit*

I will also assume you are doing this to stream a file through a non standard protocol, such as AMF, otherwise you would simply output the file over HTTP and let the browser handle the rest.